# How to access associate enum in generic way in swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I am trying to understand swift enum and for that, I decided to create a data source using an associated enum. Now I am not sure if my question line is correct or not but I'll try to explain what exactly I am trying to do here.

```
  Struct SampleClass {

       enum Country: String {
        case US(cityList: ChianCityList)
        case Chian(cityList: USCityList)
      }
      enum ChianCityList {
        case Bijing
        case Shanghai

         static var allCases = [.Bijing, .Shanghai]
      }
      enum USCityList {
        case NewYork
        case LA

        static var allCases = [.NewYork, .LA]

        var isCaptial:Bool
      }

      var country: Country

      var allCityList: [?] {
       switch self.conuntry {
       case Chian
         return CityList.allCases
       case US
         return USCityList.allCases

      }

      init(country: Country)
      {
         self.country = Country
      }
  }
```

Now I don't know what would be the return type of var 'allCityList'. I want it to be generic. secondly, I don't want to call 'allCases' for each enum. Is there anyway to make it more generic? This is just a simple example there is a lot of scenarios like this. Like 'isCaptial'. How could i make it more generic so that based on the country I can found out?

Comment: I understand that this is a learning exercise but you would never use an enum to code a long list of names.

Comment: why not use enum but struct?

Comment: The struct would only have the properties that represent a single city. The actual list of cities would come from a data file or database. The list would not be hardcoded into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, I wouldn't use `enum`s. This is because you want to store additional information about the cities (like if it's a capital city). Instead, I would use a `struct` called `City` that encapsulates all your information. Then you can have a variable `chinaCities` and `usCities` that is an array of all its respective cities.

If you truly wanted to force the use of `enum`s, I would create one giant `enum` called `City` and store an array of `City`s into two separate variables to differentiate their locations.

```
enum City: String {
    case beijing = "beijing"
    case newYork = "new york"
}
```

Of course, if you do this, you'll also have to do extra work to keep track of whether a city is a variable. One way you can achieve this is by having a function that takes in a `City` `enum` and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether it is a capital.

As a side note, I just wanted to point out that you spelled `China` and `Beijing` wrong. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am thinking about using struct now.

Comment: if you liked my answer, can you accept it as the answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `USCityList` and `ChinaCityList` are two separate types. If you return one type you can‘t return the other. You have two options.

```
enum ChianCityList {
    case Bijing
    case Shanghai

     static var allCases = [.Bijing, .Shanghai]
  }
enum USCityList {
    case NewYork
    case LA

    static var allCases = [.NewYork, .LA]

    var isCaptial:Bool
}
```

#### Option 1: Convert the one you currently return to the same type and make said type as the return type

Example:

```
enum ChianCityList: String, CaseIterable {
    case Bijing
    case Shanghai
}
enum USCityList: String, CaseIterable {
    case NewYork
    case LA

    var isCaptial:Bool
}

extension CaseIterable {
    var allCasesToStrings: [String] {
    return allCases.map{ String(describing: $0) }
}

var allCityList: [String] {
   switch self.conuntry {
   case Chian
     return CityList.allCasesToStrings
   case US
     return USCityList.allCasesToStrings
}
```

#### Option 2: Make both types conform to the same protocol, then return an instance of said protocol.

Example:

```
protocol CityList {
    var cityList: [String] { get }
    Var capitalCity: String { get }
}

// Have both implement the protocol

var allCityList: CityList {
   switch self.conuntry {
   case Chian
     return CityList.cityList
   case US
     return USCityList.cityList
}
```